# How to compare two X509Certificate2 c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I compare two X509Certificate2 objects?

I need to find whether two certificates are same. It's for user authentication purpose and I need to find if both the certificates are of the same person.

Can I use its serial number or thumprint properties? or is there any other methods?

Also I am new to this and would like to know is it safe to use X509Certificate for user authentication?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A **thumbprint** is a unique value for the certificate, it is commonly used to find a particular certificate in a certificate store. [More...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.thumbprint.aspx)

The **serial number** is a unique number issued by the certificate issuer. [More...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.serialNumber.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that's all I need to know :)

Comment: There are other unique properties on the cert but can any of them be used to not just find the cert in a store but to be certain it's the SAME unaltered cert? In other words I imagine some of them can be faked.  Is there a safe one? I figure serial number can be faked. Is Thumbprint safe? Is GetCertHash() safe? Are they the same?

Comment: Note that in .NET, the thumbprint is a SHA-1 hash which is no longer considered secure.  If you are worried about malicious input, then you should probably be sure to check that the public keys match as well, as that would guarantee that any signature validation would be validating against the correct private key.

Answer (score 4):

As @Rattle pointed out:

> The Equals method should not be used when comparing certificates for
>   security purposes. Instead, use a hash of the **RawData** property, or the
>   **Thumbprint** property.

---

Late to the party (recently needed to compare two X509 certificates myself).

The [X509Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate) class has an [Equals()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.equals) method:

> Two objects are considered equal if they are X509Certificate objects
>   and they have the same issuer and serial number.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class X509
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        // The paths to the certificate signed files
        string Certificate =  @"Signed1.exe";
        string OtherCertificate = @"Signed2.exe";

        // Starting with .NET Framework 4.6, the X509Certificate type implements the IDisposable interface...
        using (X509Certificate certOne = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Certificate))
        using (X509Certificate certTwo = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(OtherCertificate))
        {
            bool result = certOne.Equals(certTwo);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note the warning "The Equals method should not be used when comparing certificates for security purposes. Instead, use a hash of the RawData property, or the Thumbprint property."

Comment: @rattle: hmm, good point, I didn't notice that. Thanks MS for putting the warning at the bottom of the page rather than the top! Makes you wonder what equals is actually for then? I'll update my answer.

Comment: Pure speculation, but I guess someone pointed out the method of comparison was less secure, but changing the implementation would break existing valid usage so they fixed through documentation instead. Looks like the warning was only added January last year, depending how long it takes to get through to the page there's a chance it wasn't there when you looked. I wonder how much less secure it is? I guess it could allow someone with a trusted root private key to spoof a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but...

Please note that an X509 certificate is, essentially, a binding between an identity (a distinguised name, the 'name' of the certificate owner) and a public key, signed with the private key of a third-party (known as Certification Authority or CA).

X509 certificates are public, and they can be cloned, copied, etc. A certificate alone is not enough for authenticating its owner.

Authentication schemes typically must ensure that the owner possess the private key associated with the public key in the certificate, typically by performing a private-key operation like signing a challenge (a nonce or random sequence of bits). The receiver then verifies that the operation was performed with the proper private key (using the public key in the certificate). Only when both keys come from the same pair that verification will succeed (this is the essence of public key cryptography).

And, additionally, the receiver must validate the certificate: look at the issuer and owner identities, check that the issuer is an approved CA, that the certificate is appropriate for the intended usage (Validity Dates, Policy and Key Usage), that the certificate signature is valid by using the public key in the CA certificate -which is either directly trusted, or signed by a higher-level CA which is trusted-, that the certificate is yet valid (certificates expire, nothing is eternal!), and that the certificate is not revoked by the CA that emitted it.

An important thing pointed by @Rattle is that for comparing certificates (for example, when comparing a code signer's certificate with a set of approved certificates), you should not use the [X509Certificate.Equals() method](https://posts.specterops.io/subverting-x509certificate-equals-in-net-92b97d1ae59b).
Compare the thumbprints instead.